# How to change menu shortcuts?

Tags: menu, shortcuts

Im talking about shortcuts that appear in menus (for example nautilus>File>new tab   ctrl+t).

I know I had to do something to edit those shortcuts in 10.04 with .gtkrc2.0, but I forgot what it was. And it's probably different with gtk3 ..

I couldnt find ANYTHING about it, ANYWHERE, maybe because they aren't called "menu shortcuts".. So anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok .. found it ..

dconf>org>gnome>desktop>interface>can-change-accels

Im welcome.